# Get absolute position of all shapes in XWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi

Given a XWPFDocument, how does one extract absolute coordinates of all shapes contained within that document?

Regardless of whether a shape is inserted inline, or wrapping (floating) those shapes are visually rendered at some absolute coordinates on each page. How might one universally determine these coordinates in points or pixels from one corner of a page?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Sample document.xml with both inline and wrapping shapes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00BC662B" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E">
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>This is some text.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00B1405E" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E"/>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00B1405E" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E">
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Here I expect to draw a rectangle and it is positioned inline: </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <mc:AlternateContent>
          <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
            <w:drawing>
              <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="26A92917" wp14:editId="429A0BE1">
                <wp:extent cx="2037600" cy="273600"/>
                <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="20320" b="12700"/>
                <wp:docPr id="1" name="Rectangle 1"/>
                <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>
                <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                  <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                    <wps:wsp>
                      <wps:cNvSpPr/>
                      <wps:spPr>
                        <a:xfrm>
                          <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                          <a:ext cx="2037600" cy="273600"/>
                        </a:xfrm>
                        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                          <a:avLst/>
                        </a:prstGeom>
                      </wps:spPr>
                      <wps:style>
                        <a:lnRef idx="2">
                          <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
                            <a:shade val="50000"/>
                          </a:schemeClr>
                        </a:lnRef>
                        <a:fillRef idx="1">
                          <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                        </a:fillRef>
                        <a:effectRef idx="0">
                          <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                        </a:effectRef>
                        <a:fontRef idx="minor">
                          <a:schemeClr val="lt1"/>
                        </a:fontRef>
                      </wps:style>
                      <wps:txbx>
                        <w:txbxContent>
                          <w:p w:rsidR="00B1405E" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E" w:rsidP="00B1405E">
                            <w:pPr>
                              <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r>
                              <w:t>%%</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                            <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                            <w:r>
                              <w:t>text_inline</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                            <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                            <w:r>
                              <w:t>%%</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                          </w:p>
                        </w:txbxContent>
                      </wps:txbx>
                      <wps:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="0" vertOverflow="overflow" horzOverflow="overflow" vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="91440" tIns="45720" rIns="91440" bIns="45720" numCol="1" spcCol="0" rtlCol="0" fromWordArt="0" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="0" forceAA="0" compatLnSpc="1">
                        <a:prstTxWarp prst="textNoShape">
                          <a:avLst/>
                        </a:prstTxWarp>
                        <a:noAutofit/>
                      </wps:bodyPr>
                    </wps:wsp>
                  </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
              </wp:inline>
            </w:drawing>
          </mc:Choice>
          <mc:Fallback>
            <w:pict>
              <v:rect w14:anchorId="26A92917" id="Rectangle 1" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" style="width:160.45pt;height:21.55pt;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-left-percent:-10001;mso-top-percent:-10001;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:char;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:line;mso-left-percent:-10001;mso-top-percent:-10001;v-text-anchor:middle" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#10;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#10;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#10;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#10;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#10;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#10;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#10;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#10;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#10;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#10;IQALhZB+dgIAAEQFAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysVE1v2zAMvQ/YfxB0X+2kX1sQpwhSdBhQ&#10;tEHboWdFlmIDsqhRSuzs14+SHbdoix2G+SBTIvlIPpGaX3WNYXuFvgZb8MlJzpmyEsrabgv+8+nm&#10;y1fOfBC2FAasKvhBeX61+Pxp3rqZmkIFplTICMT6WesKXoXgZlnmZaUa4U/AKUtKDdiIQFvcZiWK&#10;ltAbk03z/CJrAUuHIJX3dHrdK/ki4WutZLjX2qvATMEpt5BWTOsmrtliLmZbFK6q5ZCG+IcsGlFb&#10;CjpCXYsg2A7rd1BNLRE86HAioclA61qqVANVM8nfVPNYCadSLUSOdyNN/v/Byrv9Glld0t1xZkVD&#10;V/RApAm7NYpNIj2t8zOyenRrHHaexFhrp7GJf6qCdYnSw0ip6gKTdDjNTy8vcmJekm56eRplgsle&#10;vB368F1Bw6JQcKToiUmxv/WhNz2akF/Mpo+fpHAwKqZg7IPSVEaMmLxTA6mVQbYXdPVCSmXDpFdV&#10;olT98XlO35DP6JGyS4ARWdfGjNgDQGzO99h9roN9dFWp/0bn/G+J9c6jR4oMNozOTW0BPwIwVNUQ&#10;ubc/ktRTE1kK3aYjkyhuoDzQfSP0g+CdvKmJ9lvhw1ogdT7dFE1zuKdFG2gLDoPEWQX4+6PzaE8N&#10;SVrOWpqkgvtfO4GKM/PDUqt+m5ydxdFLm7Pzyylt8LVm81pjd80K6MaoHSm7JEb7YI6iRmieaeiX&#10;MSqphJUUu+Ay4HGzCv2E07Mh1XKZzGjcnAi39tHJCB4Jjm311D0LdEPvBeraOzhOnZi9acHeNnpa&#10;WO4C6Dr15wuvA/U0qqmHhmclvgWv98nq5fFb/AEAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAB++/WfZAAAA&#10;BAEAAA8AAABkcnMvZG93bnJldi54bWxMj81OwzAQhO9IvIO1SNyokxbxE+JUqBIXJA4tPMA2XuLQ&#10;eB3FTpO8PQsXuIy0mtXMN+V29p060xDbwAbyVQaKuA625cbAx/vLzQOomJAtdoHJwEIRttXlRYmF&#10;DRPv6XxIjZIQjgUacCn1hdaxduQxrkJPLN5nGDwmOYdG2wEnCfedXmfZnfbYsjQ47GnnqD4dRi8l&#10;SPslv592pzc3v7bULV80LsZcX83PT6ASzenvGX7wBR0qYTqGkW1UnQEZkn5VvM06ewR1NHC7yUFX&#10;pf4PX30DAAD//wMAUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhALaDOJL+AAAA4QEAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#10;AFtDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAOP0h/9YAAACUAQAACwAAAAAAAAAA&#10;AAAAAAAvAQAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAC4WQfnYCAABEBQAADgAAAAAAAAAA&#10;AAAAAAAuAgAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAH779Z9kAAAAEAQAADwAAAAAA&#10;AAAAAAAAAADQBAAAZHJzL2Rvd25yZXYueG1sUEsFBgAAAAAEAAQA8wAAANYFAAAAAA==&#10;" fillcolor="#5b9bd5 [3204]" strokecolor="#1f4d78 [1604]" strokeweight="1pt">
                <v:textbox>
                  <w:txbxContent>
                    <w:p w:rsidR="00B1405E" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E" w:rsidP="00B1405E">
                      <w:pPr>
                        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                      </w:pPr>
                      <w:r>
                        <w:t>%%</w:t>
                      </w:r>
                      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                      <w:r>
                        <w:t>text_inline</w:t>
                      </w:r>
                      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                      <w:r>
                        <w:t>%%</w:t>
                      </w:r>
                    </w:p>
                  </w:txbxContent>
                </v:textbox>
                <w10:anchorlock/>
              </v:rect>
            </w:pict>
          </mc:Fallback>
        </mc:AlternateContent>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00B1405E" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E"/>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00B1405E" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E">
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <mc:AlternateContent>
          <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
            <w:drawing>
              <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251659264" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1">
                <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
                <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
                  <wp:posOffset>151200</wp:posOffset>
                </wp:positionH>
                <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
                  <wp:posOffset>288600</wp:posOffset>
                </wp:positionV>
                <wp:extent cx="5875200" cy="266400"/>
                <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="11430" b="19685"/>
                <wp:wrapNone/>
                <wp:docPr id="2" name="Rectangle 2"/>
                <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>
                <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                  <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                    <wps:wsp>
                      <wps:cNvSpPr/>
                      <wps:spPr>
                        <a:xfrm>
                          <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                          <a:ext cx="5875200" cy="266400"/>
                        </a:xfrm>
                        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                          <a:avLst/>
                        </a:prstGeom>
                      </wps:spPr>
                      <wps:style>
                        <a:lnRef idx="2">
                          <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
                            <a:shade val="50000"/>
                          </a:schemeClr>
                        </a:lnRef>
                        <a:fillRef idx="1">
                          <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                        </a:fillRef>
                        <a:effectRef idx="0">
                          <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                        </a:effectRef>
                        <a:fontRef idx="minor">
                          <a:schemeClr val="lt1"/>
                        </a:fontRef>
                      </wps:style>
                      <wps:txbx>
                        <w:txbxContent>
                          <w:p w:rsidR="00B1405E" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E" w:rsidP="00B1405E">
                            <w:pPr>
                              <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                            </w:pPr>
                            <w:r>
                              <w:t>%%</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                            <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                            <w:r>
                              <w:t>text_floating</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                            <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                            <w:r>
                              <w:t>%%</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                          </w:p>
                        </w:txbxContent>
                      </wps:txbx>
                      <wps:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="0" vertOverflow="overflow" horzOverflow="overflow" vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="91440" tIns="45720" rIns="91440" bIns="45720" numCol="1" spcCol="0" rtlCol="0" fromWordArt="0" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="0" forceAA="0" compatLnSpc="1">
                        <a:prstTxWarp prst="textNoShape">
                          <a:avLst/>
                        </a:prstTxWarp>
                        <a:noAutofit/>
                      </wps:bodyPr>
                    </wps:wsp>
                  </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
              </wp:anchor>
            </w:drawing>
          </mc:Choice>
          <mc:Fallback>
            <w:pict>
              <v:rect id="Rectangle 2" o:spid="_x0000_s1027" style="position:absolute;margin-left:11.9pt;margin-top:22.7pt;width:462.6pt;height:21pt;z-index:251659264;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;v-text-anchor:middle" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#10;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#10;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#10;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#10;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#10;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#10;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#10;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#10;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#10;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#10;IQDdhqSLewIAAEsFAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysVE1v2zAMvQ/YfxB0X50YST+COkXQosOA&#10;oi2aDj0rshQbkEWNUmJnv36U7LhFW+wwLAeHEslH8pHU5VXXGLZX6GuwBZ+eTDhTVkJZ223Bfz7f&#10;fjvnzAdhS2HAqoIflOdXy69fLlu3UDlUYEqFjECsX7Su4FUIbpFlXlaqEf4EnLKk1ICNCHTEbVai&#10;aAm9MVk+mZxmLWDpEKTynm5veiVfJnytlQwPWnsVmCk45RbSF9N3E7/Z8lIstihcVcshDfEPWTSi&#10;thR0hLoRQbAd1h+gmloieNDhREKTgda1VKkGqmY6eVfNuhJOpVqIHO9Gmvz/g5X3+0dkdVnwnDMr&#10;GmrRE5Em7NYolkd6WucXZLV2jzicPImx1k5jE/+pCtYlSg8jpaoLTNLl/PxsTn3iTJIuPz2dkUww&#10;2au3Qx++K2hYFAqOFD0xKfZ3PvSmRxPyi9n08ZMUDkbFFIx9UprKoIh58k4DpK4Nsr2g1gsplQ3T&#10;XlWJUvXX8wn9hnxGj5RdAozIujZmxB4A4nB+xO5zHeyjq0rzNzpP/pZY7zx6pMhgw+jc1BbwMwBD&#10;VQ2Re/sjST01kaXQbbrU4mQZbzZQHqjtCP0+eCdva2L/TvjwKJAWgBpGSx0e6KMNtAWHQeKsAvz9&#10;2X20p7kkLWctLVTB/a+dQMWZ+WFpYi+ms1ncwHSYzc9yOuBbzeatxu6aa6DGTen5cDKJ0T6Yo6gR&#10;mhfa/VWMSiphJcUuuAx4PFyHftHp9ZBqtUpmtHVOhDu7djKCR57jdD13LwLdMIKBhvcejssnFu8m&#10;sbeNnhZWuwC6TmP6yuvQAdrYNErD6xKfhLfnZPX6Bi7/AAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAdYUc&#10;ydwAAAAIAQAADwAAAGRycy9kb3ducmV2LnhtbEyPzU7DMBCE70i8g7VI3KjTEmgb4lSoEhckDm15&#10;gG28xKH+iWKnSd6e5QTH0Yxmvil3k7PiSn1sg1ewXGQgyNdBt75R8Hl6e9iAiAm9Rhs8KZgpwq66&#10;vSmx0GH0B7oeUyO4xMcCFZiUukLKWBtyGBehI8/eV+gdJpZ9I3WPI5c7K1dZ9iwdtp4XDHa0N1Rf&#10;joPjEaTDvFyP+8uHmd5bsvM3DbNS93fT6wuIRFP6C8MvPqNDxUznMHgdhVWwemTypCB/ykGwv823&#10;/O2sYLPOQVal/H+g+gEAAP//AwBQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAtoM4kv4AAADhAQAAEwAAAAAAAAAA&#10;AAAAAAAAAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAAL&#10;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC8BAABfcmVscy8ucmVsc1BLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQDdhqSLewIAAEsFAAAO&#10;AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC4CAABkcnMvZTJvRG9jLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQB1hRzJ3AAAAAgB&#10;AAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANUEAABkcnMvZG93bnJldi54bWxQSwUGAAAAAAQABADzAAAA3gUAAAAA&#10;" fillcolor="#5b9bd5 [3204]" strokecolor="#1f4d78 [1604]" strokeweight="1pt">
                <v:textbox>
                  <w:txbxContent>
                    <w:p w:rsidR="00B1405E" w:rsidRDefault="00B1405E" w:rsidP="00B1405E">
                      <w:pPr>
                        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                      </w:pPr>
                      <w:r>
                        <w:t>%%</w:t>
                      </w:r>
                      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                      <w:r>
                        <w:t>text_floating</w:t>
                      </w:r>
                      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                      <w:r>
                        <w:t>%%</w:t>
                      </w:r>
                    </w:p>
                  </w:txbxContent>
                </v:textbox>
              </v:rect>
            </w:pict>
          </mc:Fallback>
        </mc:AlternateContent>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>But then down here I want to float another rectangle any which way:</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00B1405E">
      <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="720"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: You can't, because `apache poi` does not rendering. No shape is positioned absolute. Inline shapes are positioned in relation to their text runs. Anchored shapes are positioned relative from either the page or the column or the paragraph or page borders. That is what you could get from the XML.

Comment: Are there any open source solutions that "effectively" render the document so that these coordinates can be retrieved, such as in the case of an export to print or PDF?

Comment: [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport) tries that. It uses different viewers and preprocessors to view and process `*.docx` files. But it is not optimal, at least when it comes to images, tables, ..., other non simple textual content.